# An Inequality, $\frac{a_1a_n}{A}\le a_1+a_n-A$

Tags: inequality

> If $a_{i+1}\ge a_{i}\ge 0$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $A$ is their arithmetic mean prove that $$\frac{a_1a_n}{A}\le a_1+a_n-A$$

So $A=\frac 1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i$, and if I define $S=nA$ and set $\bar a_i=\frac{a_i}{S}$ then, $\bar a_1\le\bar a_2\le\dots\le\bar a_n,\quad\sum_i \bar a_i=1\tag1$ and so the problem is equivalent to;

$n\bar a_1\bar a_n\le\bar a_1+\bar a_n-\frac 1 n\iff0\le n\left(\bar a_n-\frac 1n\right)(\frac 1n-\bar a_1)$ which should be true because of $(1)$.

Is this OK and  can one prove this using Chebyshev or Rearrangement inequality, also any other method is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is okay, although you should note that $\bar{a}_1\geq 0$.

You can prove it more directly.

Show your inequality is equivalent to:

$$(a_1-A)(a_n-A)\leq 0$$

Then show that $a_1\leq A\leq a_n$.

Comment: yeah silly of me.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{a_1a_n}{A} \leq a_1 + a_n - A \Leftrightarrow (A -a_1)(a_n - A) \geq 0$
(which is a reformulation of your final equation).

So the inequality is true if $A - a_1 \geq 0$ and $a_n - A \geq 0$.

To show that $A - a_1 \geq 0$:

$\forall i, a_i \geq a_1 \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \geq na_1 \Rightarrow A \geq a_1$ (by summing all inequalities, then dividing by $n$).

The same reasoning gives $a_n \geq A$.